Python: Winrm: Failed to transfer a zip file which has 10 files inside it using winrm through python3.8
I am using winrm through python 3.8 to transfer files to window vm.
My Observation

When I transfer a normal file to window. Then works fine.
When I transfer zip file which has 5-6 files inside it. Then works fine.
If transfer happens also size are not matching of zip file in source and destination.
When I transfer zip file which has more than 6 files inside it. Then fails with an error of "The command line is too long."
I tried to transfer with chunk size also still it failed.

Code:
def copy_tar_to_windows(host, username, password, local_file_path, remote_file_path):

    # Initialize WinRM session
    session = winrm.Session(host, auth=(username, password), transport='ntlm', server_cert_validation='ignore')
    
    # PowerShell command to copy the file on the remote machine
    powershell_script = f"$source = '{local_file_path}'; $destination = '{remote_file_path}'; " \
                        f"Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {{ Copy-Item $source -Destination $destination -Force }}"

    # Execute the PowerShell command on the remote Windows machine
    result = session.run_ps(powershell_script)

    # Check if the command executed successfully
    if result.status_code == 0:
        print("File copied successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to copy file: {result.std_err.decode()}")

Can someone help me on this. Thanks, in advance.
